# Eliminate empty elements from a list with a specific pattern

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I am really new in this patterns part of Mathematica. Basically what I need to do is eliminate null elements from a list but that has a specific name before the empty element. For example, my list is:

```
list={"a11-b11-{}", "a12-b11-{1}", "c11-d22-{}", "d33-c22-{2}"}
```

and I need to obtain

```
list={"a12-b11-{1}", "d33-c22-{2}"}
```

The list was created using

```
list =  Flatten[Table[ ToString[namea[[i]] <> "-" <> nameb[[j]] <> "-" <> 
        ToString[ Select[int[i, j, 0.5], Abs[#] == 0.5 &, 1]  ]], 
        {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 4}], 1]
```

and for some values it writtes `{}` because there is not a value equal to $0.5$. Until now I have been able to do it term by term as

```
list//."a11-b11-{}"-> Sequence[]
```

but the real list contains a lot of elements and could be almost impossible to do it that way to solve the problem. I think my main problem is that I am not sure how to specify the pattern search (something like " *-name " in gnu/linux). Is there a wise way to do this?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at `DeleteCases` and `StringMatchQ` or `StringContainsQ`.

Comment: I think it would be more efficient to first filter out the unwanted cases in the `int` function, and then construct strings only from the remaining ones.

Comment: @b.gatessucks Thank you, I will look those option in Mathematica.

Comment: @Roman You are right, but I am new ih this cases stuf in Mathematica and I did no know how to do it when I created the list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the list elements are strings, as it appears after your comment, you can use `Select` with a [string pattern](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WorkingWithStringPatterns.html):

```
list = {"a11-b11-{}", "a12-b11-{1}", "c11-d22-{}", "d33-c22-{2}"};
Select[list, Not@*StringMatchQ[__ ~~ "{}"]]
```

> {"a12-b11-{1}", "d33-c22-{2}"}

You could also `Select` before making the strings:

```
L = DeleteCases[
      Flatten[
        Table[
          {namea[[i]], nameb[[j]], Select[int[i, j, 0.5], Abs[#] == 0.5 &, 1]},
          {i, 4}, {j, 4}],
        1],
      {_, _, {}}];
```

and then make these into strings:

```
StringRiffle[ToString /@ #, "-"] & /@ L
```

I can't check this because you didn't supply functioning code.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to specify the way the list is created. I create the list as 'list =  Flatten[Table[ ToString[namea[[i]] <> "-" <> nameb[[j]] <> "-" <> 
     ToString[ Select[int[i, j, 0.5], Abs[#] == 0.5 &, 1]  ]], {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 4}], 1] '

Comment: Thank you. The second part of your answer was really helpfull.

Answer (score 2):

In 10.1, two functions were added to handle a pair of very common cases: [`StringStartsQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringStartsQ.html) and [`StringEndsQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringEndsQ.html) which return `True` if the string matches a pattern at the beginning or end, respectively. So, while [Roman's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/194818/52) gives you the full general form, most of the pattern can be eliminated by using

```
list = {"a11-b11-{}", "a12-b11-{1}", "c11-d22-{}", "d33-c22-{2}"};
Select[list, Not@*StringEndsQ["{}"]]
```

instead.

Comment: Than you, it looks really useful, I will try to implement it.